# I have lost my OCI Card for India and now applying for EVisa, What visa type to select under Previous Visa/Currently valid Visa Details

Tags: paperwork, india, applications, e-visas

Technically i have visited India numerous times on my OCI Card, So if say No to have you visited India before then its lying and if i say Yes, it force to select a Visa Type and OCI is not in List.
I am stuck here.

Comment: Have you tried applying for a replacement?

Comment: See the details here - https://www.mha.gov.in/sites/default/files/FAQs-200709.pdf

Comment: Re-issue process takes about 2-3 months and incase i need to travel i need to apply for EVisa, The question is related to a section in Evisa

Answer (score 8):

Choose Entry visa and put your OCI number and submit. I did that for my daughter minor and they gave me tourist visa multiple entry with no hassles. I also explained the situation of losing OCI and they told me to file the police report right away to get new OCi in leiu of lost OCI.

Comment: To file a new OCI in lieu of lost OCI, one needs the lost OCI number.  What is the process if I do not have my lost OCI number?

In the application process, the lost OCI number is mandatory and there is no information for the alternate scenario.